# Switch case (any string), is it possible in PHP?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a really simple question but I don't find any response anywhere.
I want to define a case where the value can be any string.

Is there a way in a switch case PHP to do something like this ? :

```
switch(value){

     case 0: break;

     case 1: do_something(); break;

     case [any_string] : do_something2(); break;
}
```

I was thinking maybe with an empty regex or something like this ? thanks for help !

Comment: Maybe you could make "any string" the `default` case (if that value can't be something other than `0`, `1` or some string), but in general, it seems like you need to use `if-elseif` here. Switches are designed for testing variables against static values, not dynamic ones.

Comment: Oh yes, didn't even think in it but default case could be a solution. I'll do it if there is no syntaxe to mean [any_string]

Comment: In the `default` case, you also could check if `$value` is a string [`is_string()`](https://php.net/is_string()).

Comment: I just realised that boolean mysql type, gives me back String value '0' or '1'. So I'll use the default case here for anything not boolean type. Thanks you for help !